# How do i restrict some specific special character from input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am trying to restrict '>' and '<' symbols from form input fields. I tried but not working for me. 
This is my code:

```
$('form input:text').keyup(function(e){
    var x = e.which;
    if(x==188 || x==190){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

I tried both keyup and keypress but not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052592/javascript-prevent-default-for-keyup keyup is too late

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3182548/519413. Note that if you're trying to stop someone adding HTML to the input, then this is about the least secure way of doing it

Comment: You can also have an `input` event and there just replace value by `this.value = this.value.replace(/[^,.]/g, '')`

Comment: use `regex` [Regular Expression]

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate of "restrict special characters", which recommends a regex, if OP only wants to restrict two characters using their keyCodes.

Comment: @vairakkani, If you really only need to block "<" and ">" and you don't want/need to use regex, just use keyCodes "60" and "62" instead of 188 and 190 (which are actually for comma and period). Also use `keypress` or `keydown` instead of `keyup`

Comment: Thank you @Alexandru Severin

Comment: `code`$('form input:text').keypress(function(e){
 var x = e.which;
 if(e.which == 60 || e.which == 62){
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
 }
 return true;
});